# How to get the maximum and its corresponding values in the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

how to get the first row (susan hagon, 248) in a fast way?

Comment: First? According to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name, max(count)
from   your_table
group by name
limit 1;
```

<kbd>*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ca566c3b495b289982e3223c0e1c860d)*</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate function max() and add other non aggregated columns in group by.

```
 Select name, max(count) as 'Maximum_count'
 from tablename
 Group by name
 Limit 1;
```

or

```
Select name, max(count) as 'Maximum_count'
from tablename
Group by name
order by Maximum_count desc
fetch first 1 row only
```

Comment: Does Postgresql support `top`?

Comment: @jarlh my bad.. updated my query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First get the maximum value for count in a subselect and then select all rows (only one in your case) with that maximum value

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE count = (SELECT MAX(count) FROM tablename)
```